# Triggering input click not working because of its label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**HTML**

```
<label class="filter-label" for="myId">
    <input class="filter-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="myId"/>
     <span>@item.Text</span>
</label>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.filter-checkbox').click(function() {
    //do something
}


//in another function I am calling below
$('#myId').trigger("click");
```

I dont know the reason but click trigger is working for checkbox but not for label I just want to trigger a click for label.

I think when I call trigger for #myId label also fires click event again then nothing happens. How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: This sounds like an A-B problem. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @zipzit nope it is not uniqe

Comment: This is working for me...assuming you're expecting `#myId` to trigger the `.filter-checkbox` handler

Comment: I am trying to simulate fiddle maybe it will help me to demonstrate problem

Comment: @MehmetErenYener **clear** explanation of what you want and what is the problem will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve..

```
$(".filter-label").on("click",function(){
        alert("aa");
        });

    $("#bb").on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#myId").trigger("click");
        alert("a");
        });
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/tuG6C/866/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
$('.filter-checkbox').click(function() {
    //do something
    alert('checkbox clicked');
});
```

In another function I am calling below:

```
$('#myId').trigger("click");
```